# The argument type 'CourseModel (where CourseModel is defined in C:\Users\Ali Azad\Desktop\flutter\project\pro\lib\models\Course_model.dart)

Tags: flutter, types, model

I have a model called CourseModel.

courseModel.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CourseModel {
  final String name;
  final List<String> tags;
  final String text;
  final double stars;
  final num view;
  final num students;
  final bool favorite;
  final String image;
  final String logo;

  CourseModel({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.tags,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.stars,
    @required this.view,
    @required this.students,
    @required this.favorite,
    @required this.image,
    @required this.logo,
  });
}
```

and I use that in the courseItem.dart 
courseItem.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//models
import '../models/course_model.dart';

class CourseItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final CourseModel courseData;
  CourseItem(this.courseData);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // width: 400,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 10,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                topRight: Radius.circular(5),
              ),
              child: Image.asset("assets/images/school_building.jpg"),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "مرکز عملی آموزشی ادیب",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "انگلیسی | کامپیوتر",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 30,
                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/brain.png"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                          ' کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می نماید، تا از نظر گرافیکی نشانگر چگونگی نوع و اندازه فونت و ظاهر متن باشد. معمولا طراحان گرافیک برای صفحه‌آرایی، نخست از متن‌های آزمایشی و بی‌معنی استفاده می‌کنند تا صرفا به مشتری یا صاحب کار خود نشان دهند که صفحه طراحی یا صفحه بندی شده بعد از اینکه متن در آن قرار گیرد چگونه',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.star, color: Color(0xFFf0b649)),
                                Text(
                                  "4.2",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                                Text(
                                  "145",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.people),
                                Text(
                                  "145",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                Text(
                                  "دنبال کردن",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ]),
                    )
                  ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and in my home screen I want to use course item. but I can't pass the argument(CourseModel).
I got this error = The argument type 'CourseModel (where CourseModel is defined in C:\Users\Ali Azad\Desktop\flutter\project\pro\lib\models\Course_model.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CourseModel (where CourseModel is defined in C:\Users\Ali Azad\Desktop\flutter\project\pro\lib\models\course_model.dart)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Course_model.dart(1, 7): CourseModel is defined in C:\Users\Ali Azad\Desktop\flutter\project\pro\lib\models\Course_model.dart
course_model.dart(3, 7): CourseModel is defined in C:\Users\Ali Azad\Desktop\flutter\project\pro\lib\models\course_model.dart

my home page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
// import 'dart:async';

//models
import '../models/Course_model.dart';

//Plugins
// import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
//widgets
import '../widgets/statistic_card.dart';
import '../widgets/colors_widget.dart';
import '../widgets/course_item.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = "Home";

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final List<Map> imgList = [
    {
      'image': 'assets/images/design.jpg',
      'text': 'کامپیوتر',
    },
    {
      'image': 'assets/images/camera.jpg',
      'text': 'عکاسی',
    },
  ];

  List<Map> statistic = [
    {
      "type": "شاگردان",
      "quantity": "+198",
      "icon": FontAwesomeIcons.graduationCap,
      "color": Colors.blueAccent,
    },
    {
      "type": "دپارتمنت",
      "quantity": "+120",
      "icon": FontAwesomeIcons.chartPie,
      "color": Colors.deepOrange,
    },
    {
      "type": "شاگردان",
      "quantity": "198+",
      "icon": FontAwesomeIcons.graduationCap,
      "color": Colors.blueAccent,
    },
    {
      "type": "دپارتمنت",
      "quantity": "120+",
      "icon": FontAwesomeIcons.chartPie,
      "color": Colors.deepOrange,
    },
  ];

  List<CourseModel> courseList = [
    CourseModel(
      name: "مرکز علمی آموزشی ادیب",
      tags: ["انگلیسی", "کامپوتر"],
      text:
          " کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می نماید، تا از نظر گرافیکی نشانگر چگونگی نوع و اندازه فونت و ظاهر متن باشد. معمولا طراحان گرافیک برای صفحه‌آرایی، نخست از متن‌های آزمایشی و بی‌معنی استفاده می‌کنند تا صرفا به مشتری یا صاحب کار خود نشان دهند که صفحه طراحی یا صفحه بندی شده بعد از اینکه متن در آن قرار گیرد چگونه",
      stars: 4.5,
      view: 145,
      students: 1355,
      favorite: true,
      image: "assets/images/school_building.jpg",
      logo: "assets/images/brain.png",
    ),
    CourseModel(
      name: "مرکز علمی آموزشی تسلط",
      tags: ["انگلیسی", "کامپوتر"],
      text:
          " کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می نماید، تا از نظر گرافیکی نشانگر چگونگی نوع و اندازه فونت و ظاهر متن باشد. معمولا طراحان گرافیک برای صفحه‌آرایی، نخست از متن‌های آزمایشی و بی‌معنی استفاده می‌کنند تا صرفا به مشتری یا صاحب کار خود نشان دهند که صفحه طراحی یا صفحه بندی شده بعد از اینکه متن در آن قرار گیرد چگونه",
      stars: 4.9,
      view: 185,
      students: 155,
      favorite: false,
      image: "assets/images/school_building.jpg",
      logo: "assets/images/brain.png",
    ),
    CourseModel(
      name: "مرکز علمی آموزشی چهارده معصوم",
      tags: ["انگلیسی", "ریاضی", "کامپیوتر"],
      text:
          " کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می نماید، تا از نظر گرافیکی نشانگر چگونگی نوع و اندازه فونت و ظاهر متن باشد. معمولا طراحان گرافیک برای صفحه‌آرایی، نخست از متن‌های آزمایشی و بی‌معنی استفاده می‌کنند تا صرفا به مشتری یا صاحب کار خود نشان دهند که صفحه طراحی یا صفحه بندی شده بعد از اینکه متن در آن قرار گیرد چگونه",
      stars: 3.5,
      view: 321,
      students: 155,
      favorite: false,
      image: "assets/images/school_building.jpg",
      logo: "assets/images/brain.png",
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: ColorsClass.primaryColor,
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        title: Text("صفحه اصلی"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/google_maps.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                margin:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10, left: 10),
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        blurRadius: 1,
                        color: Colors.black45,
                        offset: Offset(0.1, 0.1),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                child: Text(
                  "آمار",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )),
            Container(
              // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: GridView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Container(
                    child: StatisticCard(
                  icon: statistic[i]['icon'],
                  type: statistic[i]['type'],
                  quantity: statistic[i]['quantity'],
                  color: statistic[i]['color'],
                )),
                itemCount: statistic.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 2 / 2.2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              // height: 200,
              // width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("محل تبلیغات شما", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(80),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xFFf2709c),
                    Color(0xFFff9472),
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
              child: Text(
                "بخش ها",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                autoPlay: true,
                aspectRatio: 2.0,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                height: 200,
              ),
              items: imgList
                  .map((item) => Container(
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Image.asset(item['image'],
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                                  Positioned(
                                    bottom: 0.0,
                                    left: 0.0,
                                    right: 0.0,
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                                          colors: [
                                            Colors.blueAccent,
                                            Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                          ],
                                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                          end: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        '${item['text']}',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, bottom: 0),
              child: RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: 'بهترین ',
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headline5
                      .copyWith(color: ColorsClass.primaryColor),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text: 'کلاس ها',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: courseList.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return CourseItem(courseList[i]);
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
                autoPlay: true,
                pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: true,
                autoPlayInterval: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                enlargeCenterPage: false,
                height: 550,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have two different classes one with capital letter and another with a small letter: `\lib\models\Course_model.dart`, & `\lib\models\course_model.dart`.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much.